# Scala: unit-testing a method called asynchronously and returns a Future

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a Scala method that reads as follows:

```
    def doAnAsynchOperation(bunchedFilesUnit:BunchOfFilesUnit):
          Future[FilesHandled] = {

          val  handleFuture = future {
              BunchOfFilesUnit.unit.map(file => { 
             //FileParsing code - instantiate a class for file parsing
             //Open a fileInputStream
             //get an OutputStream
            try {
                //do some parsing, pass in a "file" invoke a parsing method
            } catch {
             case e:Throwable =>
            //some code
            } finally {
               fileInputStream.close()
              outStream.close()
            }
         })
    }
```

I am calling this method in my Unit Test written in a "describe" and inside of  it, I am going to have an "it".

There are 5 threads. Each thread is assigned the task of handling a single BunchedFileUnit .

These 5 threads are calling doAnAsynchOperation method asynchronously - each on their own - to process their own BunchedFileUnit and this method returns a Future[BunchedFileUnit].

What I want to accomplish is this:

I would like to write a test or tests to test this scenario. I would like to incorporate a timeout.

I am not very clear about the timeout concept here, but I assume I have to set a timeout and anticipate a TimeOutException. How can I lay out my test for such a scenario? This is what I want to accomplish.

Currently, I am laying out my test as follows:

```
    import org.scalatest._
    import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures
    import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, duration, Future}
    import duration._
    import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem}
    import org.scalatest.MustMatchers
    import java.io.File

    class FileHandlerTest  extends FunSpec
          with MustMatchers
          with ScalaFutures
          with BeforeAndAfter with SomeTraitThatINeeed   {

         describe("------------"){

         }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb and guess you're looking for the "[whenReady](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.1.4/index.html#org.scalatest.concurrent.Futures)" helper. I see you've already imported ScalaFutures, so you'd do something like this inside your example:

```
val files = Seq(...)    
whenReady(doAnAsynchOperation(files), timeout(Span(6, Seconds))) { result =>
  result mustEqual "the correct value"
}
```

If you're trying to test the failure condition, you could try giving it a really short timeout, but I'm not sure what that would accomplish another than ensuring it doesn't complete too fast or take too long.